# Understanding Navbar in CSS3

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML5 and i'm teaching myself to code. So if my class is navbar & i want it to hover why do I have to use navbar.a:hover? In my mind it's .navbar? Please forgive my ignorance?

```
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">History</a>
    <a href="#" class="right">Link</a>  
</div>

.navbar a:hover{
background-color:#ddd;
color:black;
```

Comment: You are correct! https://jsfiddle.net/uv7hmxac/,  Also I recommend you to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), since this should not be a question :p

Comment: According to your given CSS (.navbar a:hover) your hover will work only for <a> element inside navbar class. If you use .navbar:hover then hover will work for the whole navbar div including <a> element.

https://jsfiddle.net/r83yxuma/3/

Comment: It also depends if you want the entire bar to be changed on hover or the individual element. @Uzair is right on, but you might want to wrap the anchor tags in something larger so not just the text is changed.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to let the navbar buttons have a different background if you move your mouse over it. The elements you would want to have an effect on are the individual `a` tags then, not the whole `div` what you call navbar.

Please read about [pseudo-classes in CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) to understand the concept.